# Pull Faces of specific area

Tags: extrude

I'm trying to follow this video tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05RTwFttTE0&t=745s&ab_channel=SevengrayCubes en the minute https://youtu.be/05RTwFttTE0?t=709 it just pull down the selected faces and it looks fine.

But in my case is totalluy diferent I just extrude but result if like is show it in the picture...

[image]

How do I push the faces next to the ones that are adjacent, push them as shown in that part of the video?

Comment: maybe you're extruding the faces instead of just moving them down.

Comment: As @lemon says you're extruding rather than selecting all the faces and simply moving them downwards using G > Z as in the tutorial.